# How to implement software uart on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I want to interface gsm A6 module to raspberry pi by software uart. I am looking for a python library which will convert any gpio pin to TX and RX pin. I was trying pigpio library. there I got the serial read but whats about serial write? is it possible to implement serial write also? or is there any other library?

```
import sys
import time
import difflib
import pigpio

RX=18

try:
        pi = pigpio.pi()
        pi.set_mode(RX, pigpio.INPUT)
        pi.bb_serial_read_open(RX, 9600, 8)


        while 1:
                (count, data) = pi.bb_serial_read(RX)
                if count:
                        print data
                time.sleep(1)

except:
        pi.bb_serial_read_close(RX)
        pi.stop()
```

I want a software uart transmite function.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27488/pigpio-library-example-for-bit-banging-a-uart Look at this